# How to get proportional weights depending on its rank

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of securities, ranked $1$ to $50$ depending on how large a metric has changed.
I want to place a larger weight to the biggest mover (capped at $5\%$) and min weight to lowest mover (capped at $0.5\%$).
The sum of the weights has to add up to a $100\%$.

Can someone please explain the best way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Without capping**, you can work in this way.

Let $r_i$ be the rankings, with $r_i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 50\}.$

Then define the weights as follows:

$$w_i = 100\cdot\frac{r_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{M} r_j},$$

where $M$ is the number of securities. 
In this way, the sum of $w_i$s is equal to $100$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement the upper and lower bound?